# Why device exist in /proc/devices evethough module is unloaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am writing a simple charcter driver scull based on ldd. For my sample character driver, evethough module is unloaded device with major number exist in /proc/devices. How to remove that?

My module exit function has

```
void scull_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(Major, "scull1");
    cdev_del(my_cdev);  
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Good Bye\n");

}
```

I could see the old device with its major number when I load new module after unloading the same.

Comment: Do you get any warnings on `insmod` or on compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `cdev_del` takes a pointer, ensure that your my_cdev is a
   pointer.

   `void cdev_del(struct cdev *);`
2. It is `cdev_del`, first and `unregister_chrdev later`, it seems you
   have done it the other way, use `cdev_del` first and then      `unregister_chrdev_region`
3. You have mixed up old notation of unregister_chrdev and new notation of cdev_del.

   - either `unregister_chrdev` should be used when you use `register_chrdev` for registering

     **OR**
   - "`cdev_init`/`cdev_add` after `register_chrdev_region`" should be used in conjunction with "`cdev_del` before `unregister_chrdev_region`"

Answer (score 0):

struct cdev has an owner field that should be set to THIS_MODULE. Make sure it is set

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: In order to successfully unregister a device its owner should be the relevant module, owner is determined using owner field. for example:
cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE